# null null error in SERVER structure

Tags: coldfusion, null, runtime-error, structure

I have a SERVER variable, a structure of structures, which is highly accessed by all users (concurrency). Values are added and deleted very very frequently. Here is a small example of my SERVER variable. The real one has much more data.

```
<cfset SERVER.structure = StructNew()>

<cfset s = StructNew()>
<cfset StructInsert(s, 'test11', 'value11', true)>
<cfset StructInsert(s, 'test12', 'value12', true)>
<cfset StructInsert(SERVER.structure, 'test1', s, true)>

<cfset s = StructNew()>
<cfset StructInsert(s, 'test21', 'value21', true)>
<cfset StructInsert(s, 'test22', 'value22', true)>
<cfset StructInsert(SERVER.structure, 'test2', s, true)>
```

Every couple of hours, I loop this structure to clean expired data. However, I am getting the error "null null" while looping the variable like this:

```
<cfloop collection="#SERVER.structure#" item="key">
    <cfif StructKeyExists(SERVER.structure, key)>
        <cfloop collection="#StructFind(SERVER.structure, key)#" item="key2">
            <!--- And some code here --->
        </cfloop>
    </cfif>

    <cfif StructCount(StructFind(SERVER.structure, key)) eq 0>
        <cfset StructDelete(SERVER.structure, key, false)>
    </cfif>
</cfloop>
```

I'm receiving the error in the first line of the example. In this line, exactly:

```
<cfloop collection="#SERVER.structure#" item="key">
```

So I tried another approach. Instead of looping one by one, I created an array of keys and looped it. Unfortunately, the "null null" error was also happening there, in this exact line:

```
<cfset arrayOfKeys = StructKeyArray(SERVER.structure)>
```

My first theory is that ColdFusion can't handle the concurrency level that this SERVER variable has. I tried to use a `<cflock>` here, while clearing the variable, but it didn't work either. And I can't have this `<cflock>` where the variable is actually being used and modified by users because of the extra load that it would add (I believe).

I don't know... I'm out of ideas. Does anyone now why is this happening or have suffered this problem before? And a solution or workaround to this problem, or even a suggestion to make my code better, would be more than welcome too.

Thank you very much.

Comment: First, are you locking access to this variable? If not, it could likely cause problems due to concurrent read/write access. Second, it sounds like you could reduce concurrency issues by either replacing the entire structure OR working with a copy of it. The idea is make all of your changes on the "copy". When finished, replace the whole structure within the server scope (within a lock).

Comment: I am not locking access when I work with the variable because collisions can't happen. So I thought that a lock wasn't necessary. The structure is really big (a million "rows, more or less) so copying it all the time doesn't sound like a good solution in this scenario.

Comment: A million rows is a lot - why are you not storing the data in a database?

Comment: That's the idea, to remove database load. I'm using it like a cache. Instead of being querying the database frequently, I have this variable. And it works like a charm... but I can't loop the variable. I get the "null null" error. Any idea of why is this error generated?

Comment: So instead of writing potentially simple queries, people have to navigate a structure of structures?   Sound pretty difficult.

Comment: Adding this to the database would add a lot of load to the database, that is just what I am trying to reduce. Yes, the database would be easier, but for this case it would be less efficient. I had in mind that accessing a value in a structure having the key was a O(1). So, it's as efficient as I wanted. This loop thing is just a maintenance task to delete expired data from the variable and reduce its size. No "null null" errors, anyone? :(

Comment: Databases are designed to handle large amounts of data...like a million rows, and handle them easily. It is not a good idea to store all this data in ANY shared scope, much less the server scope. What you are doing sounds like a bade idea...a VERY bad idea

Comment: You either need to use the database or find another option. I would recommend creating something like a temporary XML file to handle this but I'm not even sure if that will work if there is a million rows. Plus, having that much data running on your coldfusion application is going to overload it more than the database server. Here is a rule of thumb when it comes to data and storing. Small amounts can be cached, large amounts need to be stored.

Comment: I am aware of caching solutions. And that what I'll implement if my idea doesn't work. Thank you very much, Peter Boughton. A XML file is not protected against concurrency and things like that. In fact, it will be slower than the database... I have reduced it to a maximum of 100k "rows" and the problem is still there. So do you really think that this is a concurrency issue that can't be fixed?

Comment: CF giving null null errors could mean anything - if you've searched you'll have seen the range of potential causes and thus disparity in solutions. If it was the server scope breaking I'm not sure I'd expect the code to break at that exact same place each time, but I've also seen CF do weirder things, so who knows. \*shrug\* Without a proper error message, the only way to figure out what's doing it is to change the involved factors one at a time until you find the tipping point(s) - and that can be a very tedius process.

Comment: What you're attempting to do here is to re-invent something that already exists; more specifically, something that has multiple mature well-tested permissively-licensed software solutions - so instead of wasting time on debugging just go with one of those working solutions.

Comment: _(p.s. XML is a terrible suggestion for this, and anyone thinking otherwise should immediately seek corrective therapy from the nearest brick wall.)_

Comment: Even if your idea 'works', it does not mean it is a good idea. This is a classic case of 'just because you could, does not mean that you should.'

Comment: Thank you very much for your attention, honestly. I'll keep monitoring it to see how it performs and if it gives problems I'll study another option, a caching solution probably. Thank you again.

Answer (score 1):

> I tried to use a `<cflock>` here, while clearing the variable, but it
>   didn't work either. And I can't have this `<cflock>` where the variable
>   is actually being used and modified by users because of the extra load
>   that it would add (I believe).

This is your problem. If you are using the server scope, you *must* lock all access to it (read and write). Otherwise you will get errors. That's the long and the short of it.

> My first theory is that ColdFusion can't handle the concurrency level that this SERVER variable has

Well: no. ColdFusion will synchronise individual operations to the server scope (well: it's handled at Java level), and that's where its job begins and ends. It's just that *your approach* doesn't handle it. Namely that you don't take steps to mitigate race conditions in your own code. This assertion of yours:

> I am not locking access when I work with the variable because collisions can't happen

Is just wrong. There's a race condition in your loop.

As others have hinted at, this is very poor application architecture, and the code is facile.

Just put the data in a database. That's what databases are for, and they're written in such a way to optimise the sorts of operation you are trying to (but not succeeding, obviously) to achieve here.

I think this is probably a case of premature optimisation: have you had this data in a properly provisioned and designed DB? Or are you second-guessing that it will be a problem? I suspect it's the latter. Or that the DB server was not properly provisioned.

Over and above the database tier, you could also use a caching tier like others have suggested.

But just don't reinvent the wheel, like others have said.

The bottom line answer to your question is that you're getting the errors because you are not correctly locking the data, and you have race conditions in your code, making ColdFusion trying to access data that you have told it is there, but could subsequently have been changed. This is due to your code, not a shortcoming in ColdFusion.

Comment: I am not getting errors while inserting or deleting data. I am only receiving the error while looping or getting the keys of the SERVER.structure variable of my example. Each user will add new entries inside their key so a user wouldn't be able to overwrite other user's data. A user could overwrite their own data inside their key, yes, but that wouldn't be a problem for the purpose of this simple feature. The keys of the SERVER.structure variable are never deleted. New keys are added, but not deleted. That's what I don't understand. Why can't I just list/loop them if they are always there?

Comment: > "Every couple of hours, I loop this structure to clean expired data." what happens is a user tries to access this data whilst it's being cleaned? But, [shrug], you've been told by a unified choir that your approach is poor. There's not much else to say, really.

Comment: The ColdFusion function StructKeyArray(), which doesn't delete anything, is also giving me the same error so... You have told me that my approach is poor but you haven't justified your opinion. If you tell me that it's poor because a structure is a Map java object and this data type is not thread safe because, for example, it's a hashmap and race conditions exist even when no data is deleted like, for example, when the hashmap is being rehashed, I will understand it and I'll falg the problem as solved. If I just have to say Ok, "I won't use it because you don't like it"... Thank you, anyway.

Comment: Look at the API's for those objects. Collection access is more complex than you may be thinking. In most languages (java, c#, ..) the API states that iterators are not thread safe. *Any* modification of a collection (ie structure), while iterating, produces unspecified behavior. The only way to guarantee thread safety is to synchronize or lock the entire operation. Example: API ["generally speaking, (it is) impossible to make any hard guarantees in the presence of unsynchronized concurrent modification"](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Hashtable.html)

Comment: BTW: `StructKeyArray` uses an iterator (to build the array of keys), just as `<cfloop collection=..">` does, so the same rules apply .. and that is only one of the potential thread problems here.

Comment: Thank you very much for you fantastic comment, Leigh. That's a very good starting point and probably the cause of my problem.